# How to stop Pandas converting integer to decimal when reading in an .xlsx file?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an .xlsx file that I am loading into a dataframe using the pd.read_excel method. However, when I do so, one of my columns appears to change format, with pandas adding a decimal point. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to stop it please?

Example of data in the .xlsx file:

```
191001
191002
191003
```

Example of the same data in the dataframe:

```
191001.0
191002.0
191003.0
```

The relevant column is using the 'General' format option in Excel.

I tried removing the decimal point with the following method; however I got the error message "*pandas.errors.IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer*".

```
df.column1 = df.column1.astype(int)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Excel doesn’t have integer values. All Excel numbers are floats. `pandas` knows this. The decimal points are a display option.  You can change the floats to integers, but every value has to be a float for that to work, as @ArchAngelPwn has explained.

Answer (score 0):

Your file most likely has infinite and nan values within the column.

You will need to remove them first

```
import numpy as np

df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
df.fillna(0, inplace = True)
df.column1 = df.column1.astype(int)
```